# How to get direction from current position to destination using google map IOS6

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hi in my application I have integrated google map now i want to give navigation direction from my  current location to destination point please tell me how to achieve this one.

My code.

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:12.9259
                                                        longitude:77.6229
                                                             zoom:6];
 mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
 mapView.myLocationEnabled= NO;
 self.view = mapView;
 GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
 marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9259, 77.6229);
 marker.title = @"Hello World";
 marker.snippet = @"bangalore";
 marker.map = mapView;
```

The above code i have used to point maker of my destination point in that please tell me how to add the navigation direction to that i have been stuck here for long time please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the comgooglemaps:// or comgooglemaps-x-callback:// URL schemes.

Note: Buttons added via the x-source parameter will not be displayed in the turn-by-turn navigation UI.

The below code snippet shows how to use the comgooglemaps-x-callback:// scheme to request directions, and then return to your app when your user is ready. The code will do the following:

Verify that the comgooglemaps-x-callback:// URL scheme is available.
Launch the Google Maps for iOS app, and request directions to JFK Airport in New York city. Leave the start address blank to request directions from the user's current location.
Add a button labelled "AirApp" to the Google Maps for iOS App. The button label is defined by the x-source parameter.
Call the fictitious URL scheme, sourceapp://, when the users clicks the back button.
The code is shown below.

```
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL]) {
   NSString *directionsRequest = @"comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
    @"?  daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York" +
      @"&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp";
 NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsRequest];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:directionsURL];
  }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device.");
 }
```

Comment: i have the destination Latitude and longitude can we use that for navigation form current location

Comment: yes u can use that or u can get that lattitude and longitude dynamically

Comment: 12.9259,77.6229 this is my latidute and lagitude of destination i want to route the direction form the current location to this point how to use this inside the code

Answer (score 0):

Go with this answer..

```
- (IBAction)handleRoutePressed:(id)sender {
    // We're working
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    self.routeButton.enabled = NO;
    self.routeDetailsButton.enabled = NO;

    // Make a directions request
    MKDirectionsRequest *directionsRequest = [MKDirectionsRequest new];
    // Start at our current location
    MKMapItem *source = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
    [directionsRequest setSource:source];
    // Make the destination
    CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.8977, -77.0365);
    MKPlacemark *destinationPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destinationCoords addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlacemark];
    [directionsRequest setDestination:destination];

    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // We're done
        self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        self.routeButton.enabled = YES;

        // Now handle the result
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error getting your directions");
            return;
        }

        // So there wasn't an error - let's plot those routes
        self.routeDetailsButton.enabled = YES;
        self.routeDetailsButton.hidden = NO;
        _currentRoute = [response.routes firstObject];
        [self plotRouteOnMap:_currentRoute];
    }];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SCStepsViewController class]]) {
        SCStepsViewController *vc = (SCStepsViewController   *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.route = _currentRoute;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Utility Methods
- (void)plotRouteOnMap:(MKRoute *)route
{
    if(_routeOverlay) {
        [self.mapView removeOverlay:_routeOverlay];
    }

    // Update the ivar
    _routeOverlay = route.polyline;

    // Add it to the map
    [self.mapView addOverlay:_routeOverlay];

}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate methods
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:        (id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    renderer.lineWidth = 4.0;
    return  renderer;
}
```

Comment: put here your destination co-ordinates and used this method according to your need 
I hope this will guide u in a proper way

Comment: i have used mkmapview before its not showing any navigation in India thats y i want to use google map please tell how to use google in ios

Comment: then my friend you should study the ios sdk of google and its documentation grom here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: i know that bro i have already used the key by clearly in my qestion u can see that i have used that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55182/discussion-between-rick4444-and-user3614966).

Comment: "Go with this answer" This is pretty close to a code-only answer. Could you explain why your answer is correct?

Answer (score -1):

If u dont want to use NSURL then you can simply use[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:]

```
 - (void)openMapsWithDirectionsTo:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)to {
        Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (itemClass && [itemClass res  pondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
          MKMapItem *currentLocation = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
         MKMapItem *toLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:[[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:to addressDictionary:nil] autorelease]];
        toLocation.name = @"Destination";
        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentLocation, toLocation, nil]
                     launchOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil]
                                                             forKeys:[NSArray  arrayWithObjects:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey, nil]]];
    [toLocation release];
}
      else {
        NSMutableString *mapURL = [NSMutableString   stringWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?"];
    [mapURL appendFormat:@"saddr=Current Location"];
    [mapURL appendFormat:@"&daddr=%f,%f", to.latitude, to.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mapURL   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
      }
   }
```

Comment: please tell me do i have add the mkmapkit and add the oulet and do i have use this please tell how to do it

Comment: please tell in this code where i have to give the destination lagitude and latitude in ur code and where to call the function